# Reading line by line C

Tags: c, find, line, fgets

I have a txt file with some file names and their size.
This is how I wrote the txt file:

```
banana //file name
3 //the size of file banana
programs
12
music
524
```

I have to find a keyboard entered file name and display it's size.

This is my code:

```
 FILE *text;
 text=fopen("text.txt","r");
 printf("Scan the number of letters of your file name");
 int n;
 scanf("%d",&n);
 char s[++n];
 printf("Scan the file name you are looking for: ");
 int i;
   for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
   {
       scanf("%c",&s[i]);
   }
 int l=0;
 char c[n];
 char g;
   while(!feof(text))
   {
       if(l%2==1) {fgetc(text); fgetc(text); l++;}
       if(l%2==0)
       {
         fgets(c,n,text);
         fgetc(text);
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
             printf("%c",c[i]);
           }
           l++;
       }
   }
```

Obviously, it's not correct. Can you help me? I'm a little bit confuse.

Comment: First observation: `feof` is not the way to do it [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). The way to go is a loop controlled by the result of `fgets` which reads one text line at a time. `while (fgets(...) != NULL) {}` then you analyse the string that was read.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=n;i++) { scanf("%c",&s[i]); }` <--- You're overflowing this buffer. Stop. Which book are you reading? Whatever it is, it's not working for you... Would you like a suggestion for a book that typically works much better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh! Please learn more about basic input. Your program has various flaws:

- `fgetc` reads single characters. This can be useful at times, but obviously you want to read whole lines. `fgets` does this. You use it once, but it is not advisable to mix these. Decide up front which input paradigm you want to use: char-wise (`fgetc`), line-wise (`fgets`) or token-wise (`fscanf`).
- Please don't make the user enter the number of characters in the filename. Quick, how many characters are there in `MySpiffyDocument.txt`? That's work that the computer should do.
- Don't use `feof` to control yopur input. All input functions have special return values toat indicate that either the end of the file was read or that an error occurred. For `fgets`, this return value is `NULL`, for `fgetc`, this return value is the special constant `EOF`. The functions `feof` and `ferror` are useful after you have encountered the special return values for a *post mortem* analysis of the two end conditions.
- Your inner loop, which is responsible for the core program logic, doesn't make sense at all. For example, for an odd `l`, increment `l` and then test for an even `l` – which will be true, because you have just incrremented an odd `l`. Use `else` in such cases. And don't place things that happen anyway in conditional blocks: Increment `l` once after the `if`/`else` blocks.

Here's an example implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int process(const char *filename)
{
    char line[80];
    char name[80];
    int size;
    int count = 0;

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (f == NULL) return -1;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            if (sscanf(line, "%s", name) < 1) continue;
        } else {
            if (sscanf(line, "%d", &size) < 1) continue;
            printf("%12d   %s\n", size, name);
        }

        count++;
    }
    fclose(f);

    return 0;    
}

int main()
{
    char line[80];
    char name[80];

    puts("Please enter filename:");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%s", name) == 1) {
            process(name);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Things to note:

- The program uses 80 characters a max. buffer size; that means your lines can be up to 78 characters long – line content plus new-line `'\n'` plus null terminator `'\0'`. That should be okay for many cases, but eventually the line may overflow. (So your file-name letter count has some merit, but the real solution here is to allocate memory dynamically. I won't open that can of worms now.)
- The code uses a double strategy: Read lines first, then scan into these lines with `sscanf`, so that only the first word on each line is read.
- Empty lines are skipped. Even lines that don't hold a valid number are skipped, too. This is sloppy error handling and may trip the odd/even count.
- Reading stuff interactively from the keyboard isn't very easy in C. The awkward `fgets`/`sscanf` construct in `main` tries to handle the case when the user enters an empty line or evokes an end-of-file signal via Ctrl-D/Z. A better and easier way is to provide arguments to the command line via `argc` and `argv`.
- I've moved the file reading into a separate function.

Comment: @MOehm Thank you so much!